# TFS - Can't stop "sub builds" which already run

Tags: tfs, build

I have a build that one of it's steps is to queue another build.

If I stop the "Parent" build his son won't be effect and will keep running.

How can I stop both of then in a single command/click?

Please suggest a generic way to do it, so I will be able to stop a "Parent" build with few sons builds.

Thanks

Comment: How have you implemented the queuing of another build?

Comment: There is a built-in activity "queue build" in the TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box.

You will need to do two or more actions to cancel each build. You could maybe create a PowerShell script but i don't know how it would know which child belongs to which parent.